# Как сменить фрагмент в методе onNewIntent

Tags: java, android

Как сменить фрагмент в методе onNewIntent, если все происходит тут:

```
 @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

   Fragment fragment = null;
   Class fragmentClass = null;
    if(fragmentClass == null) {
        fragmentClass = HelloFragment.class;
    }

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        fragmentClass = ExamFragment.class;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        fragmentClass = ResultsFragment.class;

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
        fragmentClass = RemindersFragment.class;

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    }
    if(fragment == null) {
        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Вставляем фрагмент, заменяя текущий фрагмент
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,fragment).commit();
    // Выделяем выбранный пункт меню в шторке
    item.setChecked(true);
    // Выводим выбранный пункт в заголовке
    setTitle(item.getTitle());


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: По идее можно просто вызвать этот метод, передав в него самостоятельно созданный объект меню, которому присвоен нужный id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне приходит в голову два варианта.

1. В onCreateOptionsMenu сохранить меню в какое-нибудь поле активити. Когда потребуется, вызвать `onNavigationItemSelected(menu.findItem(какой-нибудь id));`. Проблема здесь в том, что callback `onCreateOptionsMenu` будут вызван позже, чем `onCreate`, так что этого нельзя делать в onCreate.
2. Хранить набор объектов, которые будут описывать элементы меню. Например, держать эту информацию в классах фрагментов. Т. е., например, вместо `setTitle(item.getTitle());` будет `setTitle(fragment.getTitle());` и т. д..
3. Как заметил Юрий, можно создать собственную реализацию интерфейса MenuItem и передавать её в метод onNavigationItemSelected. Это будет нечто среднее между первым и вторым решением.